# Tag input from object array only add specific item to model (ng-tags-input)

Tags: ng-tags-input

Is it possible, as is, to only add a specific item form the array to the model? For example, from the [object array demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/o53tZd):

```
$scope.tags = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Tag1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Tag2' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Tag3' }
  ];
```

Is it possible to only add the "id" to the model?

```
$scope.tags = [
    { id: 1 },
    { id: 2 },
    { id: 3 }
  ];
```

Answer (score 1):

The ng-model is required, but you could disregard it and assign it to a dummy variable.  Then use onTagAdded function to add the an object containing the $tag's id property to your model's tag's array.

From the documentation:

> onTagAdded - Expression to evaluate upon adding a new tag. The new tag is available as $tag.

```
function onTagAdded($tag) {
    $scope.tags.push({id: $tag.id});
}
```

Comment: Please, don't forget to modify the html accordingly. I spent long 10 minutes to figure out why $tag remains undefined in my method. You can find an example [here](https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput/issues/63)